# gradles mustRunAfter doesnt seem to work

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I defined a task in gradle:

```
task makePretty(type: Delete) {
    println "Make it pretty!"
}
```

I want it to run after the android assemble and added this:

```
makePretty.mustRunAfter assemble
```

Unfortunally the task seems to be executed first everytime i start an gradle assemble.

```
me@my_mac: ~/sources/xxx-Android   ./gradlew assembleTest
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
Make it pretty!
```

Gradle Tasks executed:

```
:MyProject:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:preRcBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:preTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901Library UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:prepareDebugDependencies
:MyProject:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:validateDebugSigning
:MyProject:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:MyProject:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
```

My gradle wrapper is on version 1.9.

What am i doing wrong? Am I doing wrong? How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you show the order in which tasks get executed, as printed to the console by Gradle?

Comment: I added the tasks executed by gradle.

Comment: See judoole's answer. He is absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're doing your println in the configuration lifecycle. Might be there's more of an expected behaviour if you slap on these '<<'

Comment: what do they do? adding them i dont get the output of my task at all.

Comment: The '<<' appends to the task, so that it is done during execution. Not adding them means that the *println* will be done during configuration of the tasks. Might also be printed if you do a **gradle tasks**. It would seem though that your task is always UP-TO-DATE if you don't fill in any *deletes*? Could this help: task makePretty(type: Delete) { delete 'uglyFolder'; doLast{ println "Now it's pretty!"} }

Comment: unfortunally still no println happening

Comment: @Konstantin: does it execute like this: makePretty: UP-TO-DATE ? If so then **doLast** is skipped because Gradle has evaluated that the task does not require to be run, in other words 'uglyFolder' is deleted already. In other, other words makePretty must have a reason to run.

Comment: its not in the list at all unfortunally

Comment: Is it depended on? E.g. dependsOn:'makePretty'. If not I think you must run it explicitly like **gradle assembleTest makePretty**

Comment: Most likely i did something wrong, or the problem lies somewhere else in the configuration, thanks for your flexibility and answer! I will review it when i`m back on the related project.